# cordova 2.2 mapkit - map is not showing up

Tags: iphone, cordova, mapkit

I am trying to put mapkit in my phonegap (Cordova 2.2) application. I am following all the instructions but when I build the application then I get the white screen with the buttons "show,hide,shrink,zoom,clear" in the bottom of my simulator screen.
Can anyone please help me to how to show the map?

Comment: did u try it on a real device ?

Comment: Yes.. I am having same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, problem was that I have not entered the plugin name mapkitview in the phonegap.plist file

Also in the js file, sometimes if you have downloaded the older version of plugin, you need to switch between phonegap and cordova as javascript variables.